# Bash: extract data from a command-line program

Tags: bash

I know how to get the total memory in the system:

```
$ free -lm
             total       used       free     shared    
Mem:          3008       2495        513         57
```

I know how to get the main memory consumption (RSS) of worker processes in Nginx:

```
$ ps -C nginx -O rss
  PID   RSS S TTY          TIME COMMAND
 1564  1336 S ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
 1565  1756 S ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
 1566  1756 S ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
 1567  1756 S ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
 1568  1756 S ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
```

Now to determine how many worker processes my system could use without resorting to swap:

```
echo $((3008 * 1024))
3080192
$ echo $((3080192 / 1756))
1754
```

My server can handle 1754 nginx workers without resorting to swap. However, it would be great if I can take this multi-step process above and make it a single line which can be executed from command line.

My problem is I don't know how to extract that "3008" from the free command from the command line. How can I tackle this?

Comment: See the tag [tag:text-processing] on this site.  Also see [tag:sed] and [tag:awk].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is I don't know how to extract that "3008" from the free
>   command from the command line

Given this output:

```
free -lm
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3757       1765       1991        138        122        766
Low:          3757       1765       1991
High:            0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:        876       2880
Swap:         7772          0       7772
```

Try this:

```
free -lm | grep '^Mem' | awk '{ print $2 }'
3757
```

Which will return the `total` column in the `Mem:` row. In my case `3757`.

Comment: You never need to pipe `grep` into `awk`;  just do `free -lm | awk '/^Mem/ { print $2 }'`.

Comment: @G-Man Yes, you are absolutely right. Grep is not necessary in this case, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Piping free to awk will extract the value you require:

`free -l | awk '/^Mem/{print $2}'`

Comment: Note that omitting `-m` means the value is already in Kbytes and doesn't need multiplying.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

echo $(($(($(free -lm | grep Mem | awk '{print $2}') * 1024)) / $(ps -C nginx -O rss |grep 'nginx: worker process$' | awk '{print $2}' | tail -1)))

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with head, tail and cut:

```
free -lm | head -2 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -f2 -d' '
```

`head -2` because it is the top two lines.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3757       1765       1991        138        122        766
```

`tail -1` because it is the last line of that.

```
Mem:          3757       1765       1991        138        122        766
```

`tr -s ' '` - converts chains of whitespace to a single space.

```
Mem: 3757 1765 1991 138 122 766
```

Finally - `cut -f2 -d' '` - getting the second field, space delimited.

```
3757
```